# Dimension not valid while trying to add a worksheet to a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a VBA script in Workbook_A which creates a series of separate workbooks (Workbook_B, Workbook_C). The script will create these separate workbooks, name them according to variables present in Workbook_A (in this case those variables are Workbook_B, etc.), write simulation results in sheets by different simulation run, and save them.

So far, I am able to open/create new workbooks and save them correctly. I'm running into issues when it comes to creating new sheets. Here are the relevant portions of the code:

... Initializing other variables...

```
Dim workbookname As String
Dim wksht1 As Worksheet
```

... irrelevant code ...

```
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Add
    wkbk.title = savedVeh
    workbookname = savedVeh & "full"
    wkbk.SaveAs fileName:=workbookname, FileFormat:=56

    Workbook_A.Activate

    ' Starting process of creating sheets for different results
    Set wksht1 = Workbooks(workbookname).Worksheets.Add '***
    wksht1.Name = "const_speeds"
    ffastsim_validation.Activate
```

I get an error on the line with the '*** commented. The error states:

"The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type."

This is my first time playing with VBA -  am I just making a syntax error? Or is wksht1 dimensioned improperly for the operation I'm trying to perform? I'd appreciate any help explaining what's going on here.

Comment: What do you have in `Workbooks(workbookname)`?

Comment: Are you asking for the contents of that workbook? Up to that line, it is empty (but successfully named and saved).

Comment: What sheets does it have? It must have something.

Comment: Ah sorry. It has just one sheet titled "Sheet1" with no data. As if you were to open new excel document from scratch and immediately save it.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify to add after sheet1?

Comment: OK, what is the value of `savedVeh`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just Set wksht1 = wkbk.Worksheets.Add?

Comment: @sktneer - good point, but why would you get that error?

Comment: SJR: The value of savedVeh for the first iteration is the following string: 2016 TOYOTA Corolla 4cyl 2WD

QHarr: What do you mean by this? Doesn't adding a sheet put it at the end by default? Maybe I am misunderstanding.

sktneer: Hey! This worked! I'll get back to debugging to see if this works in the context of the code.

Comment: Because I guess the workbookname should be suffixed with .xls the file extension.

Comment: OK. Another useful Excel error message!

Comment: Looks like a simple mistake by me. Maybe this will sort someone out if they find this page. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do:

```
wkbk.SaveAs fileName:=workbookname, FileFormat:=56
```

And then:

```
Set wksht1 = Workbooks(workbookname).Worksheets.Add
```

If I understand correctly, that `Workbook` object you're trying to re-dereference again, would be the `wkbk` object. So why bother dereferencing it again from the `Workbooks` collection? *You already have it*:

```
Set wksht1 = wkbk.Worksheets.Add
```

Comment: I've inherited this code from another source and I'm trying to make it work for my application. So I'm dealing with understanding the code itself and learning VBA at the same time. Why bother derefencing it? No clue! I've changed it and it works great. Thanks!